# Run chroot's /etc/init.d on system startup?

Tags: linux, debian, chroot, gentoo, init.d

So I have this dedicated server that is running Debian. I have an intense business need (client's requirement) that I also install Gentoo as a Chroot.

I have successfully done so, but now, I am trying to figure out to call Gentoo's /etc/init.d from inside the chroot whenever the host Debian distribution's /etc/init.d runs (e.g., on startup).

I surely hope this is possible!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Use Linux Containers; this is one thing that they're well designed for.

For bonus points, use libvirt or one of its frontends such as virt-manager to make your life easier when managing the container(s).

Comment: Checking it out. I will report back soon.